# Sublime Text 2/3 - real-time refreshing/updating file whenever someone edited it

Tags: real-time, sublimetext, collaboration, sublime-text-plugin, pair-programming

I'm developing a project in Python using  [pair programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_programming) with someone on a separate laptop. I searched for tools that can help us with our project and saw [Floobits](https://floobits.com/). However, this plugin caused a lot of data usage and we have limited access to the internet. So I tried finding other options and managed to connect our laptops using shared folders. I used this [tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/176471/how-to-share-files-between-windows-and-linux/) (I'm using Ubuntu and my brother is using Windows). So my question is are there any way to refresh/update the file that we are editing every time someone edited just like Floobits so it will be like editing it in Real-tme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Text writes the file to the disk only when you do Save. You can configure ST to reload the file from the disk, without any prompt, when it detects the disk file changes, assuming your (network) file system supports this kind of monitoring.

I am not sure if there are ST plugins which would stream the changes for live pair edit. I am quite sure Sublime Text API is not flexible enough to do this smoothly.

Comment: So should it be like: Automatically save the file (my computer), then automatically reload the file without any prompt (other's computer) to achieve real-time editing?

Comment: I managed to automatically save the file every time I modify it using a Sublime Text plugin called [Auto-save](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/auto-save) and I turned `always_prompt_for_file_reload` to `false`. Thanks @MikkoOhtamaa !